# Is it possible to compute the matrix A if vectors x and b are known and the relationship between them is Ax=b?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I know vector $x$ and vector $b$ is it possible to compute $A$ if the original relationship is given by $Ax = b$?

Earlier I implemented some python code to rotate a 3 dimensional vector about an arbitrary axis by some angle (not relevant to the question but the code was based on the rotation matrix found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle).

I am now attempting to implement a function to reverse the original function.  That is, given: the axis of rotation, original vector, and resulting vector; the function is to return the angle of rotation.

To create this function I was hoping I could perform some matrix vector manipulations.  Is this possible or should I pursue an alternate method to solve this problem?

For reference my original function is shown below.

```
import numpy as np
def rotate_vector_about_axis(vec: np.array, rot_axis: np.array, degrees: float):
    """rotate 3d vector around a unit vector axis"""
    u_x, u_y, u_z = rot_axis
    radians = np.radians(degrees)
    adj = np.cos(radians)
    opp = np.sin(radians)
    rotation_matrix = np.array([
        [adj+u_x*u_x*(1-adj), u_x*u_y*(1-adj)-u_z*opp, u_x*u_z*(1-adj)+u_y*opp],
        [u_y*u_x*(1-adj)+u_z*opp, adj+u_y*u_y*(1-adj), u_y*u_z*(1-adj)-u_x*opp],
        [u_z*u_x*(1-adj)-u_y*opp, u_z*u_y*(1-adj)+u_x*opp, adj+u_z*u_z*(1-adj)]
    ])
    result = np.dot(rotation_matrix, vec)
    return result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot tell what $A$ is from knowing $x$ and $b$ and that $Ax = b$. As an example, let $x = b = (1, 0)^T$. Then $Ax = b$ lets us know that the first column of $A$ is $(1,0)^T$, but it tells us nothing about the second column.

In general (as long as $x\neq 0$), knowing $x$ and $b$ in $Ax = b$ gives you exactly one column's worth of information about $A$, although depending on exactly what $x$ is, that information may not manifect as an actual column unless you change your basis (it will manifest as an actual column iff $x$ is a non-zero multiple of a basis vector).

---

However, you aren't given just $x$ and $b$ in your case. You are also given two other pieces of information: That $A$ is a rotation matrix, and the axis of rotation. In that case you *can* reconstruct $A$ (assuming $x$ is not on the axis of rotation). I think the easiest way to do that is to perform an orthogonal change of basis such that the axis of rotation is parallel to the third basis vector. In that basis, we know that $A$ has the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and you can insert your $x$ and $b$ and solve for $\theta$ before you change back to the original basis.

Comment: Thanks Arthur.  I was considering how to use that extra piece of information.  Unfortunately the form of A is actually, https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f259f80a746ee20d481f9b7f600031084358a27c as it is a rotation about an arbitrary axis.

I am now considering using the cosine rule to measure the arc between the start and end vectors and somehow project that onto the plane perpendicular to the known axis of rotation.

Comment: @JohnForbes That's basically what the change of basis I mentioned above will do for you. I like to think in those terms rather than trying to solve the problem with the matrix you have there, but you do whatever you feel works best for you.

Comment: Thanks @Arthur I now understand what you meant in your answer.  I'll explore the change of basis path first.

Answer (score 1):

Given the axis by a unit vector $a$ and vectors $x$ and $b$ we know that not only they have equal lengths but also that their projections on $a$ are the same:
$$\langle a,b\rangle a=\langle a,x\rangle a.$$

Hence the angle of rotation $\theta$ is the angle between
$$x-\langle a,x\rangle a\quad\text{and}\quad
b-\langle a,x\rangle a.$$
It turns out that the cosine of that angle equals
$$\frac{\langle x,b\rangle-\langle a,x\rangle^2}
{\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle-\langle a,x\rangle^2}}.$$

Now a coordinate-free representation of the rotation is
$$b=\langle a,x\rangle a+\bigl(x-\langle a,x\rangle a\bigr)\cos(\theta)+(x\times a)\sin(\theta).$$
From here plug in the unit vectors for $x$ to get the matrix of the rotation in Cartesian base. You’ll get exactly the matrix in https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/f259f80a746ee20d481f9b7f600031084358a27c.  But it’s nicer to use the coordinate-free representation, isn’t it?